# How to unit test service depending on $controller service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller

I have a service depending on $controller service. Inside of this service, $controller service takes a controller name and locals to instantiate this controller.
When I unit test this service, I would like to pass a dummy controller name, so I can test this service properly.
From reading angular.js source code, I know $controller service looks for registered controllers by controller name. Controllers are registered through register method of $controllerProvider. How can I access this method in unit test. I'm using Jasmine here for unit testing.
Any advices are appreciated.

Comment: Friend please add your angular script and unit testing script that you have tried.just by looming question difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test Angular's $controller service, and assuming you are using ngMocks, you can use $controller normally. In Angular's documentation, there's an [example on how to use it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller).

Anyway, here's the sample from the docs:

```
describe('myDirectiveController', function() {
 it('test case', inject(function($controller) {
    // Your code goes here
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp', function ($controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.register(dummyController, function () { });
    });
});
```

I ended up with this. when my service call $controller(dummyController, controllerlocals), it was able to find this dummyController registered in its local variable controllers.
Hope this would help people have the same scenario